# Pytest doesn't see that data was updated

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi, python-unittest

I decided to write a pytest for my function bu I met a problem. The thing is that I have a function that updates the text of database cell from "open" to "hidden". And that works although the test doesn't want to accept that fact.
So, here I have this function:

```py
def hide_task_controller(task_id: int, user: UserTable):
    user = User(user)
    throw_exception_if_user_have_no_rights(user.hide_task, task_id)
```

which calls the **hide_task** method in user class. Here it is:

```py
def hide_task(self, task_id: int):
   session: Session = next(generate_session())
   task = get_task_by_id(task_id, session)
   task.state = HIDDEN
   session.commit()
```

And here is the test I'm trying to make:

conftest.py

```py
test_user_data = {
    'nickname': 'testUser',
    'email': 'test_user@gmail.com',
    'name': 'testUser',
    'surname': 'testUser',
    'password': 'testUser',
}


test_task_data = {
    'name': 'testTask',
    'subject': 'math',
    'content': 'testTask',
    'right_answer': 'testTask',
    'scores': 0,
    'rank': 'rank 10',
}


def promote_test_user_to_admin(user: UserTable, session: Session):
    user.state = ADMIN
    session.commit()


def add_task_to_public(task: TaskTable, session: Session):
    task.state = OPEN
    session.commit()


@pytest.fixture
def give_test_user_account():
    session: Session = next(generate_session())
    add_user_to_database(UserRegisterModel(**test_user_data), session)
    test_user: UserTable = get_user(UserAbstractModel(nickname=test_user_data['nickname']), session)
    promote_test_user_to_admin(test_user, session)
    task_add(TaskAddModel(**test_task_data), test_user, session)
    add_task_to_public(test_user.tasks[0], session)
    yield test_user
```

test_admin_pannel.py

```py
def test_tasks_hiding(give_test_user_account: UserTable):
    session: Session = next(generate_session())
    user = get_user_by_id(give_test_user_account.id, session)
    task_id = user.tasks[0].id
    hide_task_controller(task_id, user)
    task = session.query(TaskTable).filter_by(id=task_id).first()
    assert user.tasks[0]
    assert task.state == HIDDEN
    delete_task(user.tasks[0].id, session)
    delete_user_from_database(user, session)
```

The problem is that this test fails because the state of task after calling **hide_task_controller** function didn't change. BUT when I check this database cell, it shows me that state of task is hidden. Well, then I started to debug my code. I checked the state of task after **hide_task** method execution, inside of **hide_task_controller**. And yeah, the task changes its state, but why it doesn't changes after **hide_task_controller** executes in my test?
If you know, please tell me, I'd really appreciate it! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because `user.tasks[0]` in `test_tasks_hiding` and `task` in `hide_task` are two different objects whose state doesn't automatically synchronise? Don't you need to reload the tasks after calling `hide_task_controller` in the test function?

Comment: @tmt Well, I also tried to get tasks from db after **hide_task_controller** but the result was the same

Comment: You retrieve a user object (with tasks), then you change the value of a task - which you retrieve from the database - then you check the value in that old user object again. You never refetch (or refresh) the user - so there won't be any change in the tasks _stored inside your User object_. They're not fetched from the db again each time you access the `.tasks` property.